# International Standard for event.keyCode in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, internationalization, keyboard-events, keycode

I'm trying to code a search block that can capture any key inputs that aren't my designated escape keys and I'm having trouble confirming if different countries have different keycodes based on inputs or is event.keyCode an international standard? i.e.

```
    (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
    keycode == 32 || keycode == 13   || // spacebar & return key(s) (if you want to allow carriage returns)
    (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
    (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
    (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
    (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223)    // [\]' (in order)
```

Would these ranges work for any country or just the US?

Comment: Key codes for ASCII characters are standard. Others are not and may vary even by keyboard.

Comment: Is there a way to broad stroke input that isn't a specific keycode? I was trying to write something like if (keycode != 9 || keycode != 13 || .... ), etc to capture all input that isn't my escape keys and it wasn't even reading the input.

Comment: Keep an array of keycodes you want to ignore, then run a reduce on it to get your output? `const isEscapeKey = listOfIgnoredKeycodes.reduce((output, code) => output || code === keyCode, false)` That will tell you if the code is any of the ones on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that the non-ASCII keycodes are different internationally.
I was just using a site that was meant to fire an action when you hit the backtick key, but instead it fired when an apostrophe was typed. That's because, as you said, for a US Keyboard

```
` => 192
```

but with my UK keyboard, the keycodes are as follows:

```
` => 223
' => 192
```